# How to keep output and input separate in WinAPI console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, console

I have an issue with a console output. I'm designing a library for other developers that will provide console logging, and console input commands.
The dev should be able to type input without overwriting the output.

Currently, the console immediately draws any key the user presses. I've set it up so when a new output comes from the program, the input display gets moved, using `SetConsoleOutput` and `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.

However, the display all falls apart as soon as the user starts to backspace too far, use arrow keys outside their input area, or press Home/End. If the user's put in some input, the output will be written over it, their input redisplayed the row below, and the console cursor moved back down. But if they press Home, their cursor is positioned right back inside content they haven't typed:
[image: Example of messed up input]

Is this a lost cause, or is there a way to make this work?

As is, I have two alternatives:

1. Switch to reading [every single keypress event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events), throwing out any accessibility and localization features like IME, and adding extra complication for arrow keys, backspace, delete, etc.
2. Throw out the console entirely and use a normal window with a [Rich Edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls).

Comment: You probably want something like [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/).

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, but presumably PDCurses has a method of telling Windows how far back a backspace and Home key reaches, so I'd prefer to implement that method over pulling in a third-party library over it.
Outside of going back too high up, the console seems usable. I will consider it if there's no other suggestions, though.

Comment: Rich Edit seems to be a viable solution. The windows console is a built-in console program with limited functionality and may require very cumbersome control operations to meet your requirements.